# date conversion and comparison is off by 12 days

Tags: javascript

I have a date that is typeof string in the format of "5/12/2016". I want to convert to a date object, add 90 days and compare the dates...i.e. check if the original date is less than the new date with 90 days added to it.

I pass the date string into the Date constructor to get a date object and then use setDate method passing in 90 days. The date I get back is 78 days into the future and not 90 days. What am I missing?

```
alert(typeof startDate); // string
alert(startDate); // "5/12/2016"
var convertedStartDate = new Date(startDate);
alert(convertedStartDate); // Thu May 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)
var startDatePlusNinetyDays = convertedStartDate.setDate(90);
alert(startDatePlusNinetyDays);
startDatePlusNinetyDays = new Date(startDatePlusNinetyDays);
alert(startDatePlusNinetyDays); // Thu July 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)
```

Thanks.

Comment: [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) sets the day of the month (overflowing into the next month if necessary). If the current day is day 12, and you set it to day 90, that's 78 days into the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setDate(90)` doesn't add 90 days to the date, it just sets the day of the month to 90, so it sets the date to May 90, 2016. May doesn't have 90 days, of course, so that translates to June 59, which is again past the end of the June, and then translates to July 29.

If you want to add days to a date, get the day of month of the original date, add 90 to that, then use that in `setDate()`.

```
var startDatePlusNinetyDays = convertedStartDate.setDate(convertedStartDate.getDate() + 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `setDate()` is doing what you think it is. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), the setDate() method sets the day of the Date object relative to the beginning of the currently set month.

Try something like this, maybe:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days){
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
    return this;
};

var startDatePlusNinetyDays = convertedStartDate.addDays(90);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var startDatePlusNinetyDays = convertedStartDate.setDate(90);` you're *setting* the date to `90`, not incrementing the date.

The reason it's 78 days incremented is because the initial date was `12` (as in the 12th of May) and you're setting it to `90` such that `90 - 12` is `78`.

Try

```
var startDatePlusNinetyDays = new Date(+convertedStartDate + 24 * 3600000 * 90)
```

which will take the converted start date and add 90 days (in milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

When adding dates, you may want to consider using the following convention, which differs slightly than your current approach :

```
// This will add a specific number of days to the existing date
function addDays(d, days) {
    var newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + days);
    return newDate;
}
```

This is different than the use of the [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) function alone which sets the day relative current month which can be seen in this example and demonstrated below :

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id='testing'>
    <tr>
      <th>Days Added</th>
      <th>Using setDate(days)</th>
      <th>Using setDate(getDate() + days)</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var start = "5/12/2016";
      for (var i = 1; i <= 90; i++) {
        // Using setDate() alone
        var setDate = new Date(new Date(start).setDate(i));
        // Using getDate() + i
        var getDate = addDays(new Date(start), i);
        // Add rows
        $("#testing").append('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + format(setDate) + '</td><td>' + format(getDate) + '</td></tr>');
      }

      // This will add a specific number of days to the existing date
      function addDays(d, days) {
        var newDate = new Date(d);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + days);
        return newDate;
      }

      // Format for example purposes
      function format(d) {
        return (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You'll quickly notice that when adding a single day using your existing method, the result is `5/1/2016` as it is setting the day to the first day of the month as opposed to adding it to the existing date. Since you are starting on `5/12/2016` that indicates that there will be roughly 12 days difference between the two results overall, which is similar to what you experienced.